# How to specify source jar for Cucumber stepdef

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have some scenarios which call a stepdef from a jar included as a dependency.

Now, I want to maintain 2 separate versions for the same stepdef into 2 different jars. Since I need few scenarios to use version 1 and others to use version 2 of the stepdef.

How do I do this with `@CucumberOptions`, specifically mentioning jar source in the `glue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using the following approach:

1. Created 2 separate JUnit runners for running version 1 and 2.
2. Supported both versions of step definition by maintaining 2 packages.
3. Mentioned respective package name using `step.provider.pkg` property in `@CucumberOptions` `glue` specification for both the runners.

Note regarding maven:

I had to include both the runners in maven [`failsafe`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) plugin to run tests during `integration-test` phase. Also had to provide 2 separate `executions` in `failsafe` plugin to enable ordered execution of mentioned runners.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know it is not supported in cucumber. We are using [QAF-gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) which support steps in jar and two different implementation for same step with support to load appropriate implementation at run time using `step.provider.pkg` property.

Comment: Yeah, I solved this using `step.provider.pkg` property a while ago.